# two date cells - i want 3rd cell to some value

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, spreadsheet

I have two cells with completed installation dates. I have a 3rd cell where I need to input outstanding installations.

If the 2 cells have dates, it means the installation is complete so I want the 3rd cell to show 1 or 2 to show 1 or 2 completed installs.

How do I do this in excel?

Thanks

Comment: If your first two cells are A1 and A2 then you could e.g. use `=COUNT(A1:A2) & " installs completed."`. Is it what you need?

Comment: Thinking ahead, will there be cases of more than two installs?

Answer (score 1):

Like @Máté mentioned, it depends on what exactly you want to see.

If you need to see the specific details summarized, you can use a combination of IF() and AND() statements, like:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>"",B2<>""), "#1 & #2 Completed",IF(A2<>"","#1 Completed", IF(B2<>"", "#2 Completed", "None Completed")))
```

If you just wanted to see an overall count of progress, you can use what @Máté mentioned in the comments (COUNT works because dates are stored as numbers):

```
=COUNT(A2:B2) & " installs completed."
```

I'm assuming you Dates are in A2 & B2.

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry about that. I updated the formula to say "None Completed" in that case.